# Duplicate Breadcrumbs in Rails using Gretel gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, breadcrumbs

I'm using the Gretel gem to add a breadcrumb trail to my custom built photo gallery.

The relationships between the gallery models are:

Collection:

```
has_many :children, class_name: "Collection", foreign_key: "parent_id"
belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Collection", foreign_key: "parent_id"
has_many :albums
```

Album:

```
has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
belongs_to :collection
```

I then have some Gretel crumbs defined as:

```
crumb :collection do |collection|
  link collection.title, gallery_collection_path(collection)
  if collection.parent
    parent :collection, collection.parent
  else
    parent :gallery
  end
end

crumb :albums do |parent_collection|
  link parent_collection.title, gallery_collection_albums_path(parent_collection, :albums)
  parent :collection, parent_collection
end
```

Bu when navigating I get a trail like the one that follows as soon as I reach an album:

> Home › Gallery › Days out › Theme Parks › Alton Towers › Alton Towers

The URL for the first "Alton Towers" is

> /collections/617

and for the second is:

> /collections/617/albums

I think something to do with my Collections controller is messing it up as my Collections Show  action redirects to my Albums Index action if the collection has no children, (therefore needing to display the list of albums)

The Collection Controller is:

```
   def index
      @size = :medium
      @title = 'Gallery'
      @collections = Collection.roots
   end

   def show
      @collection = Collection.find_by_id(params[:id])
      if @collection.has_children?
         @collections = @collection.children
         @size = :medium
         @title = @collection.title
      else
         redirect_to [:gallery, @collection, :albums]
      end
   end
```

Any ideas as to how I can solve this so I get the desired output below when viewing my Albums Index page?:

> Home › Gallery › Days out › Theme Parks › Alton Towers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding a bit of extra logic to the collection crumb to see if the child is an album and if so it skips outputting a crumb for that step